# How to get access and refresh token from AWS cognito authorization code

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have configured Facebook as federated identity provider with authorization code. After successful authentication I receive the authorization code but can't find a way to get the access and refresh token in AWS .net SDK. Only option that I found is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html but is there any existing method in .net SDK for this?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [Cognito Authentication Extension Library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito): refreshing a session with a refresh token is [documented here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito#authenticating-using-a-refresh-token-from-a-previous-session). The refresh token for a signed in user can be access through `user.SessionTokens` attribute which is an instance of [`CognitoUserSession`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/blob/e9ee8c3d9ac88ece13fb0dd22ad01c4575330b23/src/Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication/CognitoUserSession.cs#L23)

Comment: Thank you but I only have the authorization code from Facebook as a federated identity provider. I don't have the access token or refresh token

Comment: Once you receive the authorization code, you need to pass it with additional parameters such as redirect URL, client ID of cognito to receive the access,ID token, refresh token
[link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/)
Try this for a detailed understanding [Token Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html)